# SharePoint Server Subscription Edition cannot connect with Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint, visual-studio-2022

I am not able to connect SharePoint Server SE to Visual Studio 2022.
So, I am getting this error when I am trying to create a new SharePoint empty project from visual studio

[image]

I have checked those steps:

1. Run VS as administrator 2.The user is set as sysadmin of the SQLServer, as well as db_owner of the following DBs.
   a. WSS_Content
   b. Sharepoint_Admin_Content
   c. Sharepoint_Config
2. The user is owner of the SP and has full control.
3. The site is added to the IIS host file.
4. I have cleared VS cache.
5. This also occur when I am trying to import SharePoint Solution File. (.wsp)

I am using SharePoint Server Subscription Edition and Visual Studio 2022 Community.

Note: I checked SharePoint Server 2019 and Visual Studio 2019 and this combination works fine.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Please try to make sure below:

1. This http://testnet is accessible in browser
2. Did you enabled any Alternate access mapping or any entry in host file
3. Create New Website via SharePoint Central Admin and try again.
4. Deploy the same solution with different Web Applications URL.